# WordPress Admin Restricted access

Tags: wordpress, admin

The following code to restrict access to wp-login.php and wp-admin works for me, but could someone tell me if I miss something? I placed it in my function.php

```
if ( ! is_super_admin() && ! preg_match( '#admin-ajax\.php#', $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] ) ) {

    if ( preg_match( '#^/wp-#', $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] ) || preg_match( '#wp-admin#', $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] ) ) {

        wp_safe_redirect( 'https://...' );
        exit;

    }

}
```

Comment: How is someone supposed to log in at all? If they're not already authenticated, won't they fail the first test?

Comment: No, because using a custom signin page